# Automatically replicating database structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I Have two databases in MySQL : 
"**dbjava**" which is the production database
"**fake_db_java**" which is the test database.

I Would like to configure **fake_db_java**(test) so that each modification in **dbjava**(production) structure(not content) is automatically done in the test database.

Is this possible through configuration or should I consider writing scripts to handle this?

Comment: `TRIGGER` to the rescue.

Comment: But triggers only acts on data manipulation (INSERT DELETE UPDATE) not structure(CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE).What i need is to reflect structural changes(such as adding new tables).

Comment: How about database replication MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with PHP whether the given values are already in the database or not. If not you can get these values and put them in the other database. This requires to run the script once in a while or put it on a VPS though.

Comment: I don't need to check for value changes I need to check for structural changes (ones that takes place on the tables structure not content).

Comment: Oh, I missunderstood that. Then I'm afraid I can not help you. Good luck!